# Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using the Client Object Model with adfs c#

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint-online, adfs

I have a problem with my connection to an intranet (SharePoint Online with ADFS).

I use this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c#content) ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh147177(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

The sample worked well for a long time but now the "LoginPageUrl" is always null.

I searched but there is not a lot of explanation on this error. I am a little lost.

Someone would have an idea where could the problem come from?

Thank you.

**UPDATE** I debug the sample and I have an exception in Header properties when I try to get response from webRequest. Why?

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
        webRequest.Method = Constants.WR_METHOD_OPTIONS;

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = (WebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            ExtraHeadersFromResponse(response, out loginUrl, out navigationEndUrl);
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            ExtraHeadersFromResponse(webEx.Response, out loginUrl, out navigationEndUrl);

        }
```

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful for you: [Get the name of the full URL list](https://www.codesd.com/item/get-the-name-of-the-full-url-list.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not help me.